# PHP get timestamp for a specific day last month

Tags: php

Can I use strtotime() to obtain the timestamp for a given day 'last month' and if not what is the most efficient way of doing this?

This is the kind of thing I want

```
strtotime("5 last Month");
```

instead of

```
$time_day= 5;
$time_month= date("m");
$time_year= date("Y");

if($time_month<1){
$time_month=12;
$time_year--;
}else{
$time_month--;
}

$date=mktime(0,0,0,$time_month,$time_day,$time_year);
```

Comment: I don't think down grading is right I'm looking for some code efficiency not any old answer..

Comment: Be more specific about your needs! Post what you have tried so far, your code, errors and such. We are not wizards!

Comment: Yes, you can. That's the answer to your question, be more specific for getting better answers (and no downvotes).

Comment: `$time_month= date("m");` should be `$time_month= date("n");` (m = minutes, n = months) and `if($time_month<1){` should be `if($time_month==1){`

Comment: thanks for spotting that although m is the month with leading zeros

Comment: Seen, undownvoted and answered.

Comment: Please see my revised answer. I believe it accomplishes what you want. :)

Comment: This is an old question, but I just needed same thing, this is how I get 20. day of the last month:

strtotime('+19 days', strtotime('first day of last month', $timestamp));

Comment: Everyone is over thinking this.  `strtotime` will work here:  `$xDate = date('Y-m-21', strtotime('previous month')) ;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortuantely what you want to do is not currently possible using `strtotime()` in PHP. Here's how to achieve what you want in one line, using [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```php
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') - 1, 21);
```

The above code will find the timestamp for the **21st** day of the previous month. Just swap `21` for whatever you want.

This works because:

> Values less than 1 (including negative values) reference the months in the previous year in reverse order, so 0 is December, -1 is November, etc. [[PHP Documentation]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

So if the month was `1` (January), you would be running `mktime()` with `0` as the month value, which means 'December in the previous year'.

Comment: Thanks xenon that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for

Comment: @Xenon - is wrong about strtotime....you can retrieve a specific day of previous month: 
 `date('Y-m-21', strtotime('previous month')) ;` - will give the 21st day of the previous month

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`mktime()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: I was hoping to use the last month feature in strtotime and keep it all on one line rather than have to calculate what last month was first.

Comment: date('n') == 1 ?  12 ? ((int)date('n')) - 1;

Answer (score 0):

### Bug

First, I need to correct a little bug:

```
if($time_month<1)    // If month==0
    {
    $time_month=12;    // New month==12
    $time_year--;
    }
```

In that way, there are 13 months... ( 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 ). [Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) specifies that `date("m")` goes from 1 to 12, then that code should be:

```
if($time_month==1)    // If month==1
    {
    $time_month=12;    // New month==12
    $time_year--;
    }
```

### Don't optimize

And a second thought, I wouldn't bother trying to optimize it much more. Remember that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). If your code works and it's relatively short (which is the case), the best would be to leave it that way. Think that EVEN if there was a function to do what you wanted, the only difference would be that you don't have to program the code yourself, but the background process would be really similar so there's not so much to optimize (about speed/resources).

### Comment your code

Also, I'd recommend writing one or two lines of comments saying what it does. It will be useful to understand the code if you want to reuse it in, say, one year or so.

One last thought. Different months have different days. I'm not sure if your code is to be used with manual input or depending on the current day, but what would happen if you wrote `day="31";` and `date("m")` is 03?

### Possible solution

Take a look at  this: [Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php). It works in this way:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-20');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));    // 10 days ago
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

It will output `2000-01-10`

Comment: The solution works in the same way than your code, even with the same possible bug (as seen in one example).